# How to distribute web assembly package

Tags: webassembly

I am using WebAssembly in a project. I would like to package the wasm part of the project into its own module and hopefully distribute the standalone binary. I've not found anything like a 'wasm repository' so far. It would be great for web developers to be able to include a 3rd party wasm binary in their projects as easily as other web libraries (using npm or bower for instance).

My questions:
1) Does a 'wasm repository' exist right now?
2) If not, what are the biggest challenges that need to be addressed before distributing wasm modules is as ubiquitous as distributing other web libraries?

---

Edit: For anyone curious, here is a github thread on the topic: https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/320

Answer (score 1):

If the wasm file format/multiple file is a problem, there is a flag

```
-s SINGLE_FILE=1
```

which outputs the Emscripten glue code together with the wasm in a single JS file.

Of course this is not at all an optimised solution, but I think it will help in some cases.

[You can read more about SINGLE_FILE flag in this Emscirpten pull request](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/5296)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to distribute wasm that way(yet). I assume that you are looking for something like a  C shared libraries. Hopefully that will be possible in the future so that we can develop  wasm libraries and used them in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish WASM modules using npm. As most consumers would be using it in Node or a browser anyway, this would be the most convenient for them. It would also allow you to distribute JS loading/glue code (as produced by Emscripten or whatever), as well as example and test code.